# creating text files out of a text file by extracting lines between two character lines

Tags: java, text-files

I'm going to read a corpus that is segmented by "##################" and put each segment in a separated  text file. My corpus is like below:

#####4327 (Judicial System)

ofobcbyfwquote  A   right
sd  A   uh actually i lived over in europe for a couple of years
sd  A   i lived in germany
sd  A   and in germany they dont have the jury system

#####4423 (living right)

sv  B   i think what they need to do is they need to somehow *lipsmack* take the money out of it
sd  B   i mean when you have a man thats signed a a a statement saying hes guilty
sd  B   we have a a family called all day family

I need two text files out of it that named 4327 and 4423 and contain text in between. I know the standard model of reading text files and used it a lot:

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Train.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8"));
        String line="";
        while ((br.readLine().startsWith("#")))
            {
```

But do not know how to command it to create text files out of each segment?

Comment: Create a new `Writer` which uses the new `File`...

Comment: How to pick lines between two (############) lines?

Comment: `String#startsWith`, if it doesn't start with `##...` then write to the current file.  If it does, close the current file and open a new one...

Comment: Yeah it was easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regual expression, you can use ApacheCommon for reading files to String:http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File).

The code will be something like this:

```
File fileToParse = new File("/path/to/file");
String complete = FileUtils.readFiletoString(fileToParse);
String[] fragments = complete.split("\\#+[0-9]+");
```

May be you need to improve regex and save every fragment, you also can use FileUtils.

I hope it help you.